# Read only file system -Truecrypt volumes

Tags: mount, permissions, read-only, chown, truecrypt

I am having problems with truecrypt volumes being a Read-only file system. I created the volumes on a windows machine and have used them without much trouble on ubuntu.

I have had trouble before with the drives suddenly becoming read only, although running fsck this fixed the problem.
When I run fsck now it says "Dirty bit is set Fs was not properly unmountedect. ect. ect although when I remove the dirty bit nothing changes.
I have tried running Chown but it just returns;

```
chown: changing ownership of '/media/truecrypt1': Read-only file system
```

I have also tried to disable journaling but i'm not even sure if this is needed and I didn't have much luck anyway.

I would really appreciate all help as I have been scratching my head all day, I'm pretty new to linux and not the sharpest tool in the box so if you could try and give simple instructions it would be appreciated.

Many Thanks.

Comment: Truecrypt is discontinued. Use Veracrypt instead.

Comment: Is it a NTFS partition?

Comment: Problem is sorted I think. When I plug the card into my laptop it sometime pushes the lock button on the card, should look for the simple things first I guess. Still getting read only message when I try to move files but I can at least work with them now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I just experienced the same issue.

The resolution for me was:

**Boot into a Windows machine, mount my Truecrypt volume, then disconnect the volume.**

I must not have done the disconnect last time the drive was connected which caused issues with Linux being able to mount it read/write.

I also did a partial chkdsk /r if that matters but I think the important bit was mounting in Windows then safely dismounting.